# WCF service no answer. PHP result Error Fetching http headers,

Tags: php, wcf

I have WCF service

```
[ServiceContract(Name = "Test")]
public interface ITest {
    [OperationContract]
        string test1();
}
[DataContract]
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerCall, ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Single, UseSynchronizationContext = false)]
public class csTest : ITest {
    public string test1() {
        Thread.Sleep(60000);
        return "test1";
    }
}
```

start them

```
ServiceHost TestHost= new ServiceHost(typeof(HostHCS.Test.csTest), new Uri("http://127.0.0.1:8150/Test"));
            ServiceConfigureHttp(TestHost, crtSMBHttp("127.0.0.1","Test","8150"), crtSDB(), typeof(HostHCS.Test.ITest), crtBndHttp(), ip, "Test");
            TestHost.Open();
private void ServiceConfigureHttp(ServiceHost service, ServiceMetadataBehavior serviceMetadataBehavior, ServiceDebugBehavior serviceDebugBehavior, Type serviceType, BasicHttpBinding bind, string ip, string servName) {
        service.Description.Behaviors.Remove(typeof(ServiceMetadataBehavior));
        service.Description.Behaviors.Add(serviceMetadataBehavior);
        service.Description.Behaviors.Remove(typeof(ServiceDebugBehavior));
        service.Description.Behaviors.Add(serviceDebugBehavior);
        service.AddServiceEndpoint(serviceType, new WSHttpBinding(),"");

        service.AddServiceEndpoint(
System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceMetadataBehavior.MexContractName, 
System.ServiceModel.Description.
MetadataExchangeBindings.CreateMexHttpBinding(), 
 "http://127.0.0.1:8150/Test/mex");
    }
    private BasicHttpBinding crtBndHttp() {
        BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
        binding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = Int32.MaxValue;
        XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas readerQuotas = new XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas();
        readerQuotas.MaxArrayLength = Int32.MaxValue;
        readerQuotas.MaxStringContentLength = Int32.MaxValue;
        readerQuotas.MaxBytesPerRead = Int32.MaxValue;
        readerQuotas.MaxDepth = Int32.MaxValue;

        binding.ReaderQuotas = readerQuotas;
        binding.MaxBufferPoolSize = Int32.MaxValue;

        binding.OpenTimeout = new TimeSpan(1, 00, 0);
        binding.CloseTimeout = new TimeSpan(1, 00, 0);
        binding.SendTimeout = new TimeSpan(1, 00, 0);
        binding.ReceiveTimeout = new TimeSpan(1, 00, 0);
        return binding;
    }

    private ServiceMetadataBehavior crtSMBHttp(string ip, string servName,string port) {

        ServiceMetadataBehavior myServiceMetadataBehavior = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
        myServiceMetadataBehavior.HttpGetEnabled = true;
        myServiceMetadataBehavior.MetadataExporter.PolicyVersion = PolicyVersion.Policy15;
        return myServiceMetadataBehavior;
    }
```

My php code

```
<?php
try{ 
ini_set('default_socket_timeout', 600); //120/// 6000//60000
$client = new SoapClient(
'http://127.0.0.1:8150/Test?wsdl',
array(
    'soap_version' => SOAP_1_2, 
    'cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE, 
    'trace' => 1,
    'exception' => 1,
    'keep_alive' => 0,
    'connection_timeout' => 60000//500000
));
$webService = $client->test1();
} catch (Exception $e) {

print  'Caught exception: '.  $e->getTraceAsString(). "<br/>";
print  'Caught exception: '.  $e->getMessage(). "<br/>";
var_dump($client->__getLastRequestHeaders());
print    "<br/>";
var_dump($client->__getLastRequest());
print    "<br/>";
var_dump($client->__getLastResponse());
print    "<br/>";
}
?>
```

returns the result very quickly

> Caught exception: #0 [internal function]:
>   SoapClient->__doRequest('__call('test1', Array) #2 {main}
>
> Caught exception: Error Fetching http headers
>
> string(204) "POST /Test HTTP/1.1 Host: 127.0.0.1:8150 Connection:
>   close User-Agent: PHP-SOAP/7.3.2 Content-Type: application/soap+xml;
>   charset=utf-8; action="http://tempuri.org/Test/test1" Content-Length:
>   186 "
>
> string(186) " "
>
> NULL

That is, there is no call to the service method, since the result should be received only after a minute. what could be the problem and what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The error was as follows.  PHP does not work with WSHttpBinding and if replaced

```
service.AddServiceEndpoint(serviceType, new WSHttpBinding(),"");

service.AddServiceEndpoint(serviceType, new BasicHttpBinding(),"");
```

And in php client change version soap client

```
'soap_version' => SOAP_1_2,

'soap_version' => SOAP_1_1,
```

then everything will work